# Convert List Like String to Python Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have string variable which contains list like values

How To convert string values to dataframe?

```
string = '[[2017, 1050], [2016, 1069], [2015, 1173]]'
pd.DataFrame([item for item in string])

# Giving wrong results
```

Need result like below

```
      0     1
0  2017  1050
1  2016  1069
2  2015  1173
```

Also, second column contains special characters like (s) -- NA w * - etc

**ast.literal_eval** raises an exception if the input isn't a valid datatype.
How to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html), list comprehension is not necessary:

```
import ast

string = '[[2017, 1050], [2016, 1069], [2015, 1173]]'

df = pd.DataFrame(ast.literal_eval(string))
print (df)
      0     1
0  2017  1050
1  2016  1069
2  2015  1173
```

Comment: ast.literal_eval raises an exception if the input isn't a valid datatype
how to overcome this? List string contains different data types

Comment: @SPy - Can you add sample of this bad data? But obviously it is not easy :(

Comment: @SPy - I try some regex and failed. Maybe possible solution should be split, do you parse json file to `list`s ?

Comment: yes parsing json file. Also I am getting some other error: ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Ellipsis object at 0x000002010009A668>

Comment: @SPy - OK, data are confidental?

Comment: @SPy - For me it working nice, like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52383636/2901002) - `DF = pd.read_json(sourcePath, lines=True)`, for you it failed?

Comment: pd.read_json fine but pd.DataFrame(ast.literal_eval(DF.Data)) gives error "ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Ellipsis object at 0x000002142E2C3208>"

Comment: So solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52386049/2901002) not working? Also added your original code.